# System Network Certificate window Frozen

Tags: wireless, networking, gnome, internet, certificates

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, with gnome-shell.

I try to connect to a secure wi-fi network.

I enter my login and password, but no certificate -- I'm instructed by my university to ignore the warning (I know this is bad, but...).

Said warning appears (dialog entitled "No Certificate Authority certificate chosen"), but it is completely frozen.
Neither the "Don't warn me again" checkbox, or the button react to my clicks.
The window manager can not even close the dialog, I have to xkill it.

Does any know know of any workarounds or fixes for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem and it was really bugging me until I finally found a workaround for it.

You must simply try to connect to the network using another protocol without a certificate (LEAP). After trying to connect with LEAP, go back into your network settings and hit the arrow on the right of the network you are trying to join. This will open a new window with a settings option.

Click 'Settings...' then go to the 'WI-FI Security' tab and here change it to the protocol that uses a certificate and enter all the details.

The warning will still come up but should not freeze now when you make your changes. Tell me if this works for you or if you don't understand :). Also, I'm not completely sure but you may have to restart your computer after the changes are made.